# Running Stored Procedure in SSIS Child package, SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I can run the child package on its own just fine. Package runs, stored procedure fires and updates a table as expected (stored procedure is aggregating some data and updating a second table with the results).

When I run it from its parent package the stored procedure appears to execute (I can see it in SQL Server profiler) however the table is not updated by the procedure. Other tasks within the child package run fine, both when the child package is run on its own and when run by parent.

This is running by SQL Server Agent job, deployed on SQL Server 2012. If I run the parent-child in Visual Studios, the stored procedure fires and the table is updated.

Seems that the stored procedure is not running when deployed. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does it say anything about the execution in the SSIS Progress tab?  There should be an entry in there for when it attempted to run it.

Comment: You are referring to visual studios I assume? It runs OK in vs, only fails in deployed mode.

Comment: Strange - does the account it's running under have access to the stored procedure?

Comment: @Anthony: What is the error you are getting, there might be a security issue for your agent job. here are some tips for trouble shooting http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918760

Comment: @Anthony what you are describing sounds like the child package is not getting the correct connectionstring for its new environment.  Check the logs for your connection values at runtime.  If you have package level parameters for the child package, those would need to be configured in the execute package task of the master package.